# How does one run code within the browser at Run-time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor

I have been using the documentation here https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/304655/how-to-programmatically-compile-code-using-c-compiler
I am trying to learn about compilers a bit more I want to host on my own site a simple text editor that I can use to run the code of a script say something simple like

The program is required to Print out Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

If anything other than Hello World is printed out the program would be in error.

I have been looking at Microsoft code on running .net code at runtime but both these force it to create an exe I want the result to be like .net fiddle in a text box.

I presume what I have to do some how is run the exe and use the process to return the result bare in mind this is inside a mvc applicaiton.

Or is their any cool nugets that can save me the time here.

```
private void Compiler(string code)
{

  CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
  ICodeCompiler icc = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();
  string Output = "Out.exe";
  System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new 
  CompilerParameters();
  //Make sure we generate an EXE, not a DLL
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
        parameters.OutputAssembly = Output;
        CompilerResults results = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);

        if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
        {

            foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
            {
                CompilerError error = new CompilerError();
                error.Line = CompErr.Line;
                error.ErrorNumber = CompErr.ErrorNumber;
                error.ErrorText = CompErr.ErrorText;                   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Successful Compile

            CodeResult result = new CodeResult();
            result.Message = "Success";


        }
}
```

So how would one capture the above and return and also how does one add support for other languages like python or vb.net

Is this something that blazor could perhaps be good at doing for me ?

I am wanting to provide an experience like .net fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net

Comment: "within the browser", your mention of Blazor is probably the only thing that runs in the browser in your question. ASP.NET runs on the server, not in the browser. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes I changed my question I want to do something like .net fillde does running the code in the brower with the output https://dotnetfiddle.net

Comment: dotnetfiddle doesn't run it in the browser, they run it on the server, they just heavily sandbox it.

Comment: And by "heavily sandbox it" I mean this: If you're not sure what kind of technology you could use to correctly run user-provided C#/.NET code through a web browser, **don't**!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! If you do it wrong, you're opening up your whole server to the internet.

Comment: You mentioned .NET Fiddle. I'm pretty certain that works by sending the code you write to the server, compiling and executing it and sending the result back. I don't think any of the magic happens in the browser itself

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen who said this was a real-world application I am experimenting in this tech to better learn and understand .net fiddle started exact same way by leaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suchiman / Robin Sue is has integrated the Monaco editor as well as an in-browser C# compiler in [this nifty blazor project](https://github.com/Suchiman/Runny) ([live demo](https://runny.azurewebsites.net/))

Comment: thank u exactly what i was after many thanks tewer its just as a learning curve I presume this will handle whatever assemblys are on the target server?.

Comment: Ok many thanks for this this been exaclty what I been looking for just will have to sandbox it allot to ensure dont have access to the io classes

Comment: The IO classes does not work on the WebAssembly platform, they will throw NotImplementedException. The only IO you have is HttpClient, and sandboxed browser-specific storage like localStorage, sessionstorage etc (but you need plugins or interop to access them)

Comment: I deleted my comment about "loading whatever assemblies". The code I initially referenced will only load build-time dependencies. If you want to reference assemblies unknown at build-time you will have to override the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event and download more assemblies from the server, or make the user upload them into the browser before using them...